# nppiFilterGaussBorder_8u_C1R oSrcSize and oSrcOffset parameters

Tags: cuda, nvidia, npp

I would like to run `nppiFilterGaussBorder_8u_C1R` just on a part of an image.
The [documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/npp/group__image__filter__gauss__border.html) says the following:

> `pSrc`: Source-Image Pointer.
>
> `oSrcSize`: Source image width and height in pixels relative to pSrc.
>
> `oSrcOffset`: The pixel offset that pSrc points to relative to the origin of the source image.

Based on this my understanding is:

If I have a 10x10 image, and I would like to apply `nppiFilterGaussBorder_8u_C1R` on the `TopLeft{x:2, y:2}` `BottomRight{x:8, y:8}` area

- `pSrc` should be `image.ptr + 2 * 10 + 2` [an offseted pointer that points to the second row second column]
- `oSrcSize` should be `{10-2, 10-2}` [Source image width and height in pixels relative to `pSrc`]
- `oSrcOffset` should be `{2, 2}` [The pixel offset that `pSrc` points to relative to the origin of the source image.]
- `oSizeROI` should be `{8-2,8-2}`

But if I calculate my parameters like this I get `NPP_OUT_OFF_RANGE_ERROR` in some cases (when the rect is on the bottom of the image e.g.). So most probably my understanding is not correct.

Could you please help me how I should set `pSrc`, `oSrcSize` and `oSrcOffset` in the mentioned example?

**EDIT: Demo code:**

The code uses 256x256 images instead of 10x10, the blurred area should be from `TopLeft{0, 224}` (inclusive) to `BottomRight{256, 256}` (exclusive). `nppiFilterGaussBorder_8u_C1R` returns `NPP_OUT_OFF_RANGE_ERROR`

```
#include <npp.h>
#include <nppi.h>
#include <istream>

int main() { 
    Npp8u* cudaMem = nppsMalloc_8u(256 * 256);
    Npp8u* cudaMemDst = nppsMalloc_8u(256 * 256);

    if(cudaMem == nullptr)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Error malloc");
    }

    if(cudaMemDst == nullptr)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Error malloc dst");
    }

    if(auto const memsetRes{nppsZero_8u(cudaMem, 256 * 256)}; memsetRes != 0)
    {
        std::cerr << "nppsZero_8u failed " << memsetRes << std::endl;
    }

    if(auto const memsetRes{nppsZero_8u(cudaMemDst, 256 * 256)}; memsetRes != 0)
    {
        std::cerr << "nppsZero_8u dst failed " << memsetRes << std::endl;
    }

    NppiPoint const blurTopLeft{0, 224};       //inclusive
    NppiPoint const blurBottomRight{256, 256}; //exclusive

    //Source image width and height in pixels relative to pSrc.
    NppiSize const oSrcSize{256 - blurTopLeft.x, 256 - blurTopLeft.y};
    NppiSize const oSizeROI{blurBottomRight.x - blurTopLeft.x, blurBottomRight.y - blurTopLeft.y};

    auto const nppiError{nppiFilterGaussBorder_8u_C1R(
        cudaMem + blurTopLeft.y * 256 + blurTopLeft.x,
        256,            // pitch
        oSrcSize,       // source image width and height in pixels relative to pSrc.
        blurTopLeft,    // aka. oSrcOffset: The pixel offset that pSrc points to relative to the origin of the source image.
        cudaMemDst + blurTopLeft.y * 256 + blurTopLeft.x,
        256,            // dst pitch
        oSizeROI,
        NPP_MASK_SIZE_3_X_3, 
        NPP_BORDER_REPLICATE
    )};

    if(nppiError != 0)
    {
        // We get NPP_OUT_OFF_RANGE_ERROR
        std::cerr << "nppiFilterGaussBorder_8u_C1R failed: " << nppiError << std::endl;
    }

    nppsFree(cudaMem);
    nppsFree(cudaMemDst);
}
```

Comment: @paleonix nope, NPP_BORDER_REPLICATE should handle that. If I pass {0,0} as TopLeft and {256, 256} as oSizeROI [so basically the whole image] it works.

Comment: @paleonix from the documentation: "If any portion of the mask overlaps the source image boundary the requested border type operation is applied to all mask pixels which fall outside of the source image." It is fine if the input ROI is smaller than the image, this is exactly why we provide oSrcOffset - it knows this way that it can sample from the previous lines.

Comment: @paleonix It supports even 15x15 mask, I tried it with TopLeft{3,3} e.g. and it worked. The error occurs if oSrcOffset's y is larger than height/2 or oSrcOffset's x is larger than width/2.

Comment: according to my testing, you will get the expected output (with no errors) if you pass the actual source image size for `oSrcSize`, so in your case that would be `NppiSize const oSrcSize{256, 256};`  No, I don't have answers for all the questions that engenders.  I have found NPP parameter handling to be inscrutable at times. You're welcome to [file a bug](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/how-to-report-a-bug/67911) to request doc clarification.

Comment: @RobertCrovella thanks for checking it. I'm not sure if it is the right way to pass the oSrcSize{256, 256}, as nppiFilterGaussBorder_8u_C1R might sample outside the image this way. If it starts from cudaMem + 224 * 256 + 0 and thinks that there is 255 more rows in the input and calculates the last row of the output image (y==255), then the function doesn't know that it shouldn't sample from input's 256 and 257th row as they are out of bounds. I file a bug, thx!